# How to get a trivial case of Spring MVC view (JSP) resolving to work?

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

My app uses Spring MVC (latest; 3.2.2) to create a RESTful API returning JSON, and so far I haven't needed a view layer at all. But now, besides the API, I need a simple utility page (plain dynamic HTML) and wanted to use JSP for that.

I want requests to `http://localhost:8080/foo/<id>` to go through a controller (Java) and end up in a JSP. Should be simple, right? But I'm getting 404; something is not right in resolving the view.

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /jsp/foo.jsp. Reason:

    Not Found
```

**Controller**:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{id}")
 public String testing(@PathVariable String id, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("id", id);
    return "foo";
 }
```

Defining controllers and mapping requests works; this method gets called just fine.

**Spring config**:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

The problem is probably here. I've experimented with slightly different prefixes and putting the JSPs under `WEB-INF`, as well as stuff like `<mvc:view-controller path="/*" />` but no luck yet.

(Do I even need to specify InternalResourceViewResolver, or should default view resolvers take care of this?)

**JSP files**. Under `src/main/webapp/jsp` (the project uses Maven conventions) I obviously have the JSPs.

[image]

Is there something wrong with this location?

**web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have browsed through [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), but my problem is probably too trivial and obvious to easily find help there. :-P

Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need to do is changing

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`/*` won't match if there is another folder in the path, like `/jsp/foo.jsp`. On the other hand `/` will match everything.